# jQuery Mobile Styling Loaded Content from Another File

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am looking to find a way to have jQuery Mobile render data being loaded onto the page. I know that very similar topics has been discussed mn the past, but nothing seems to be a perfect match (or close enough to result in me finding an answer).

The issue is that jQuery mobile will dynamically apply classes to HTML elements when a page is loaded. Content being pulled in through JavaScript does not get transformed because the process is run before the JavaScript content is placed onto the page. The fix for this supposedly is to use the .trigger('create') function. It seems though that this doesn't work when you use the load() function to pull content from external pages.

I am able to get the data from the twitter.html file (example below) just fine, it just isn't being formatted via jQuery Mobile

To help demonstrate my point, I've tried to put together some starter examples of the script. Unfortunately because I am loading an external file there is no easy way to represent this issue without saving the files to your computer to test them out.

**Main file** (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" />

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#container').load('twitter.html');
            $('#container').trigger('create');
         });
    });//]]>  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <!-- Load the Twitter Data -->
        <div id="container"></div>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Sample</li>
            <li><a href="#">Ignore this</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">And look for Twitter data above</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!--/content-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**File being called** (twitter.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=10&q='jquery'";
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
        var twitterList = $( "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='c' data-dividertheme='b' />" );
        $.each( data.results, function( index, item ) {
            $( "<li />", { "text" : item.text } )
                .appendTo( twitterList );
        });
        $( "#tweets" ).fadeOut( "fast", function(){
            $( this ).empty()
                .append( twitterList )
                .fadeIn( "slow" );
        });
    });
});

</script>

<div id="tweets">Loading Tweets...</div>
```

Can anyone provide an example of a working method to call a file in this way?

**Pages that I've looked into related to this:**

I have like 10 pages to reference, but I'm a noob on this site so I am limited to just 2.

1. http://blog.stikki.me/2011/08/18/loading-dynamic-content-in-jquery-mobile-with-jquerys-load-function/
2. http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2011/3/15/jQuery-Mobile-styling-loaded-content

I've literally spent the past 7 hours trying to work this out, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am brand new to the world of JavaScript, so please take it easy on me.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, In JQM, the loaded pages are not suppose to use $(document).ready. If you are in control of the page that is coming from the external source, than please modify the function to pageInit, otherwise, you will need a way to hook into the function call that external page is making.

Try extending the functions that downloaded page is calling. In this example: $.getJSON. In the extended function, wrap success function with your function that does pageCreate after executing the success function.

[JQM Reference:](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to either trigger "refresh" event on updated elements, or "create" on parent element of newly added added elements after you've changed the HTML. E.g. `$('ul').listview('refresh')`.